# twisted reactor.spawnProcess opens an unwanted console when cx_freeze'd

Tags: python, twisted

Basically it's all in the title, when I run the code from a console (on Windows) the child process runs without opening another console, but when I run the code from the cx_freeze'd app another console opens.

I found this old thread where was suggested to use FreeConsole(), it will flash the console on screen for a blink but I can eventually live with it, unfortunately if i understood correctly it should be called from the child process.

http://twistedmatrix.com/pipermail/twisted-python/2007-February/014738.html

I also found this ticket (7yo) on a re-factoring of the whole spawnProcess on windows but apparently it never happened:

http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/2415

I have no control over the code of the child process, so doing something there is unfortunately not an option, but even if I did the process I'm spawning it's a console app and I believe FreeConsole() could not be called there or the process will terminate.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly a bug in Twisted, but possibly a bug in `cx_Freeze`.

What happens when you run the code from the GUI with Python, but without `cx_Freeze` involved?  You should be able to test this if you have Python installed by simply putting your code into a `.pyw` file and double-clicking on it in Explorer.

If this still pops up a console window when you run your subprocess, then this is totally a bug in Twisted and you should file it as such.  Eric's answer in that mailing list message is wrong; if you want to spawn processes with `spawnProcess` they definitely shouldn't be popping up random console windows.

If the click-on-a-`.pyw` launching method *doesn't* cause a console window to pop up, then it's probably something about the way `cx_Freeze` has constructed your executable and you might want to look at it.

On UNIX, we have a platform-specific `usePTY`, so it makes sense that we could expand `spawnProcess` with a platform-specific `useConsole` that would do something analogous for Windows.  [This later message in the thread](http://twistedmatrix.com/pipermail/twisted-python/2007-February/014757.html) suggests an implementation strategy, so [please file a ticket](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/newticket).  The let's-redo-everything ticket is too ambitious to fix this one issue.

Comment: I can confirm that cx_freeze isn't doing anything wrong, even using pythonw spawns a console window, having a useConsole flag for spawning processes on windows would be great, I'll file a ticket. Thanks

Comment: OK, cool.  Thanks for eliminating that complexity.  Also, please post a link to the ticket here so others can find it easily in the future!